# DoCmd.OpenForm with a Like in Access is not working for me

Tags: vba, ms-access, sql-like

I'm pretty new at Access and I am trying to open a form with a like filter using the code

```
Private Sub AddCOB_Click()
Dim FilterLike As String
    If Nz(JobSwitch, 0) = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Please Select a Job")
        JobSwitch.SetFocus
    Else
        FilterLike = "[ID] = LIKE '" & jobNUMBER & "*'"
        DoCmd.OpenForm "AddCOF", , , FilterLike
    End If
End Sub
```

I keep getting [Runtime error 3075](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqXgE.png)
`jobNUMBER` is a public variable declared in a module and defined in this form, that seems to be working fine. This message is showing what I believe is the right syntax. I also checked it with a `MsgBox`. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Can someone please show me the error of my ways?

Answer (score 0):

`=` and `LIKE` are different comparison modes. Access expects you to use one or the other.

In your case, use `[ID] LIKE`

```
FilterLike = "[ID] LIKE '" & jobNUMBER & "*'"
```